# Cannot access wp-admin (hacked)

Tags: wordpress, security

After moving the site to a new host, but WITHOUT changing the address, I can access the website - http://www.morelhifi.com , but cannot access /wp-admin - http://www.morelhifi.com/wp-admin/ . The page looked like it was hacked. Someone did hacked to the website few months ago, but we fixed it. This page started to appear only after I moved the website.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `http://www.morelhifi.com/wp-login.php`?

Comment: Thanks! but still i'll be happy to know how to fix the /wp-admin problem...

Comment: What does the /wp-admin look when you are logged in?

Comment: Like the page the hacker created - black and green. No dashboard.

Comment: You will need to go back through the website because the code left by the hacker wasn't fully removed.

Comment: but where can i find it?

Comment: It could be hidden anywhere. My first suggestion would be to download a copy of the site and view the source of the /wp-admin file and try find some of that.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to blow away the entire WordPress site and recreate it. Restore everything from a backup from before the site was hacked.

Comment: Installing patches and changing passwords of course before it is made available to the world.

Answer (score 0):

For this repairs, everytime: 
**1-** Download Last WP.
**2-** Upload wp-includes and wp-admin folders from zip
**3-** Check wp-content folder and sub folders with anti-virus programmes